# Query returning unexpected value

Tags: sql, sql-server

So I have the following query:

```
SELECT CASE 
         WHEN (SELECT COUNT(col) 
               FROM   table 
               WHERE  <some conditions>) = 0 THEN 0 
         ELSE (SELECT col 
               FROM   table
               WHERE  <some conditions>
              ) 
       END
```

The first statement with the count returns 0 however the case statement seems to jump to the else clause and subsequently returns a value where no value exists.

Here is the issue replicated in a fiddle:

http://sqlfiddle.com/#!6/6ae7c3/3

Thoughts?

Comment: If the conditions are the same, it wouldn't really be returning a value, it would be returning `NULL`.  You should try to reproduce the problem on SQL Fiddle or at least include sample data and the real code.  My suspicion is that your expectations are wrong.

Comment: So yeah, conditions are the same, also, if I change the col returned after the else clause, to something other than col, the query returns the correct value (thoughts?) also, in the process of replicating in fiddle now!

Comment: Looks OK to me... the COUNT(*) is 0 and CONVERT(DATETIME,0) is 'January, 01 1900 00:00:00+0000

Comment: Additionally it looks like you can return different data types ie. int and nvarchar.  changing the count clause to '0' from simply 0 will eliminate this sub issue.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This isn't a bug.  It is returning `0` but cast as a `datetime`.  You can get the same thing as:

```
SELECT cast(0 as datetime)
```

If it went to the `else` clause, it would be returning `NULL`.